# UART Blocking Mode and Non-Blocking Mode

Tags: stm32, uart, rs485

I want to using RS485 communication between two or more device using stm32 + tranceivers, I need to request-response type communication so RS485 bus will have many data. Which one would make sense to use for a communication blocking mode or non-blocking mode, and why ? Which one is more healty for the systems running ?

Comment: Do you have an operating system that supports UART functionality?

Comment: No. I dont have

Comment: What is your communication protocol? Is it "single master & multiple slaves"?

Comment: single master and multiple slaves, half duplex

Comment: You don't say any details what other things your system must do, so as it is you can use either.

Comment: What I want to learn is in what kind of systems these two communication methods are used.

Comment: You want non-blocking mode. Almost never blocking mode is a good choice in the real system

Comment: Do you know what blocking means? If I write an answer explaining blocking, will I be wasting my time? A blocking read, with no OS to perform task switching means that when the processor is waiting for input, no other code can execute. The processor will not do anything until input comes over the UART. It would be very rare that this is desired, although it makes the code very simple.

Comment: This URL explains blocking and non-blocking driver
<https://www.beningo.com/embedded-basics-blocking-vs-non-blocking-drivers/>